# Save data from database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have created an application with internal database LightSwitch..

Now I want to publish my application and I want to publish also data of my internal database..How can I do?

for example : I have an application Fantacalcio and I created some players in my internal database of lightswitch..now when I publish my application and I install it in my pc there are no data in my application.. I want that when I install my application there must be players that I have created before..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically in something like Application_Initialize, or in a SQL script.

LS has no "built-in" way to pre-populate data, so it's a matter of choosing a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to do the following:

1. Attach the lightswitch internal database to SQL server
2. Export all the data into a SQL script, [here are the instructions](http://www.beletsky.net/2011/02/how-to-export-sql-data-script-for-sql.html)
3. After you have the sql script (mostly INSERT statements), then run
   the script on your designated database.
4. The exact same data should now be populated there.